# Is it grammatically correct if I change "came" to "comes" in this sentence? If so, what is the difference in their meanings?

Tags: grammaticality, tenses

If I were Joe Kelly's wife, I would never get that window fixed, and I would just make him explain what happened every time someone **came** over.

Comment: I'd use 'came' unless I was in the room with the broken window (and I'm housesitting for the Kellys, and I know Joe Kelly by reputation but don't know Mrs Kelly ...).

Comment: They are both grammatical, and there is no effective difference in meaning in this context. But, with that, *came* implies a single instance, whereas *comes* can imply something continual or repeated (a general habit). However, because of the use of *every time*, that difference is mostly negated. (And the use of *came* in this particular sentence without *every time* would only be correct if you changed *would* to *could*.)

Comment: @JasonBassford: Same basic construction: *If I didn't smoke myself, I would make you go outside when you **light** up* (or *...when you **lit** up* - it's all the same to me). I can't see that switching from ***would*** to ***could*** affects the ***light / lit*** choice.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it correct to say "What was your name?"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/3255/is-it-correct-to-say-what-was-your-name)